# Convolutional Neural Network for time-dependent features

Tags: neural-network, convolution, feature-extraction, feature-selection, conv-neural-network

I need to do dimensionality reduction from a series of images. More specifically, each image is a snapshot of a ball moving and the optimal features would be its position and velocity. As far as I know, CNN are the state-of-the-art for reducing the features for image classification, but in that case only a single frame is provided. Is it possible to extract also time-dependent features given many images at different time steps? Otherwise which is the state-of-the-art techniques for doing so?

It's the first time I use CNN and I would also appreciate any reference or any other suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to have the network somehow recognize a progression which is time dependent, you should probably look into recurrent neural nets (RNN). Since you would be operating on video, you should look into recurrent convolutional neural nets (RCNN) such as in: http://jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v32/pinheiro14.pdf

Recurrence adds some memory of a previous state of the input data. See this good explanation by Karpathy: http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/

In your case you need to have the recurrence across multiple images instead of just within one image. It would seem like the first problem you need to solve is the image segmentation problem (being able to pick the ball out of the rest of the image) and the first paper linked above deals with segmentation. (then again, maybe you're trying to take advantage of the movement in order to identify the moving object?)

Here's another thought: perhaps you could only look at differences between sequential frames and use that as your input data to your convnet? The input "image" would then show where the moving object was in the previous frame and where it is in the current one. Larger differences would indicate larger amounts of movement. That would probably have a similar effect to using a recurrent network.

Comment: Thanks! A RCNN seems what I need and the paper is very interesting. I think I should try something like: I give X sequential pictures to the RCNN and it should give me a good approximation of the features representing the scene, considering also the difference in the ball movement.